# i do not understand tag <input checked>

Tags: html

I'm new to the Html and discovered that people use 'checked' attribute in their input tags. what does it change? I have tried to google this question but nothing comes up that answers my question.

Answer (score 0):

when you have an input type of checkbox, the checked attribute means that that checkbox will already be checked

Answer (score 0):

The checked attribute is a boolean attribute.

When present, it specifies that an  element should be pre-selected (checked) when the page loads.

The checked attribute can be used with  and .

Answer (score 0):

This attribute is used on checkbox inputs.
It specifies that an  element should be pre-selected (checked) when the page loads.

Answer (score 0):

The Check attribute of  is used only for check boxes and radio buttons. When you add checked in the input tag, it will make the radio button to active state and checkbox to check.

You will learn these in the way.
More Information: 
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_checkbox.asp